Is it possible for a REST API to be called only by the frontend app's domain?
I have a website that has an Angular frontend (https://dev.myApp.com/) and a .NET 8 REST API (https://dev.dataAPI.com/api/),
Both of these are hosted on different on prem servers.
If i click on a button in my frontend, it calls the REST API with with this method:
data(): Observable<Response> {
    const path = `${this._apiUrl}/Parameter/Data`;
    return this._http.get<Response>(path);
  }

This is how the call is logged in the browser's console: https://dev.dataAPI.com/api/Parameter/Data
This is what it returns to the app:
{
    "success": 1,
    "message": "Ok",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 27,
            "descri": "URUGUAY"
        }
    ]
}

Here's the problem: If i know the full url of the get request and i paste it on my browser, it also works:

This to me feels like it's very unsafe. We are not sharing any sensible data in responses, and anything that could be is in POST requests so whoever wanted to run them like this would have to know the format of the body of the response, but i still think that maybe this shouldn't be possible in the first place.
We are not using something like tokens to secure the communication with the API yet, so i have to think about something else for now.
I've read that i could do something with CORS, but i also read that it's very easy to circumvent. This is how CORS is set up in my API:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsApi",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("*")
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .AllowAnyMethod());
});

So first of all, is this normal behavior or it's something i should be worried about?
Is it possible for my API to check who is calling it and make it so the request doesn't execute if it didn't came from my APP?

you just want to authenticate/authorize users.  Make sure backend requires authentication/authorization for any requests that need to be secured.  (It'll also be helpful from a security standpoint if api and frontend are on same domain... keep everything same-domain and you are more secure against cross-site vulnerabilities. You won't need to set any CORS headers then... those are loosening your users' security)

We can implement this feature by using custom middleware.
The reason why this requirement can be achieved

When accessing the API through a browser, there are no Origin and Referer http request headers.

Here is my test code
In my test environment, I am using memory cache for testing, in your production environment, you can us redis or others.
ApiKeyAndDomainMiddleware.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class ApiKeyAndDomainMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

        public ApiKeyAndDomainMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            _next = next;
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var apiKeyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IApiKeyService>();

                var apiKey = context.Request.Headers["x-api-key"].FirstOrDefault();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiKey))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("API Key is missing.");
                    return;
                }

                if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue("ApiKeys", out Dictionary<string, string> cachedApiKeys))
                {
                    var apiKeys = await apiKeyService.GetApiKeysAsync();
                    cachedApiKeys = apiKeys.ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Value);

                    var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                        .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)); 
                    _memoryCache.Set("ApiKeys", cachedApiKeys, cacheEntryOptions);
                }

                if (!cachedApiKeys.TryGetValue(apiKey, out var validDomain))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 401; 
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid Api Key.");
                    return;
                }

                var origin = context.Request.Headers["Origin"].FirstOrDefault();
                var referer = context.Request.Headers["Referer"].FirstOrDefault();
                var requestDomain = origin ?? referer; 

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestDomain) || !requestDomain.StartsWith(validDomain))
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = 403; 
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid domain.");
                    return;
                }

                await _next(context);
            }
        }
    }
}

ApiKeyService.cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class ApiKeyService : IApiKeyService
    {
        private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

        public ApiKeyService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            _memoryCache = memoryCache;
        }

        public async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetApiKeysAsync()
        {
            if (!_memoryCache.TryGetValue("ApiKeys", out Dictionary<string, string> apiKeys))
            {
                // Mock Data
                apiKeys = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "test123", "https://dev.myApp.com" }
                };

                var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));

                _memoryCache.Set("ApiKeys", apiKeys, cacheEntryOptions);
            }

            return await Task.FromResult(apiKeys);
        }
    }
}

IApiKeyService.cs
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public interface IApiKeyService
    {
        Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GetApiKeysAsync();
    }

}

Program.cs
using WebApplication2;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

// Add API Key Service
builder.Services.AddScoped<IApiKeyService, ApiKeyService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyAndDomainMiddleware>();

app.UseAuthorization();



app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Since it is difficult for ordinary browsers to add the x-api-key http request header. In addition, through our back-end verification, we can check the source of the request again, and access it after matching, which can improve security.
If you are worried about your server being attacked by malicious and frequent requests, you can consider using Rate limiting middleware in ASP.NET Core.

The short answer is "most likely, no". CORS controls whether you can access data from a page that is served by different URL, in your case https://dev.myApp.com, but CORS doesn't prevent anybody to simply enter https://dev.dataAPI.com/api/ in the browser.
If you really need to limit the data on the server to specific sources, you should do that through networking tools, like whitelisting IP of the client - not through the application code. Obviously, if you want to protect the data from inside the application, you should be using authentication, such as OpenID Connect and JWT token.
If your requirements warrant, you can use both firewall and authentication tools.
